# How are complex applications made with Python in an IDE with raw code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

The question may not have been clear as there was not much of a better way for me to word it but I will do my best here: Most scripting is done raw in the IDE. When coding with Python it simply runs everything through the "console." I was wondering how full-on apps with different screens and all that cool stuff are made with Python as well, other than just being a console with many different commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about gui (graphical user interface) applications tkinter module is what you're looking for allowing you to create simple gui applications.

Here is a link to the documentation 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

should be included in python by default.

Comment: Oh, yes. I was looking for the right words to describe it. Assuming I use it, will it also pull up the GUI when I run it?

Comment: Yes it will,  when you run the program in the terminal it will open up the gui as a new window.

Comment: Alright, that helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you want to design cool stuff with colours and nice picture, you can use turtle. Turtle is a cool library which allows you to draw turtles and other cool animations. Useful for beginners like you :)

Comment: Oh, nice! Is there a link to the library or the resource information?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Comment: Thank you very much.